# How to shift focus to next/previous tab in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to achieve arrow key navigation on the tabs in ExtJs 4.2.2, right now i have one of the tabs selected, i want to use keyboard arrows to navigate to other tabs.

here is what i have done. but its not working... i'm getting error '`next is not defined`'
what am i doing wrong here.

```
var keyNav = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
        binding: [{
                key: Ext.EventObject.UP,
                fn: function(){ this.next().focus() }
            },{
                key: Ext.EventObject.DOWN,
                fn: function(){ this.prev().focus() }
            }, {
                key: Ext.EventObject.LEFT,
                fn: function(){ this.prev().focus() }
            }, {
                key: Ext.EventObject.RIGHT,
                fn: function(){ this.next().focus() }
            }
        ],
        scope: this
    });
```

Comment: are you sure `this` is a reference to tabpanel?

Comment: @pvlt this is reference to tab, but not tab panel.

Comment: can you post code for all your panel? of create fiddle

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `this` in the handler still does not refer to the tab. Try to put a debugger in it and see. It might be worth tying `keynav` through [target](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap-cfg-target) property with your tab's.